# Induction / (machine learning) of Resource Grammars for Grammatical Framework?

Tags: machine-learning, reference-request, formal-grammars, induction, computational-linguistics

Grammatical Framework is based in **Abstract** Categorial Grammars. It is known that **Combinatory** Categorial Grammars have grammar induction/learning capabilities see e.g. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11168-007-9026-2 and there are also works about statistical learning in Cornell Semanatic Parser framework. But what about abstract CG generally and GF specifically - can GF resource grammars be machine learned/induced - are there works about this? Google gives nothing, but Google is not reliable with such searches.